# find/create a tool to generate java sources(model/controller/dao) in spring mvc

Tags: spring-mvc, code-generation

I am using spring mvc3 now,and I found that most of my controller own the same logic. For exmaple:

PostController:

```
package com.king.controller;

@Controller
@RequestMapping("/posts")
public class PostController {
    @Autowired
    private PostDao postDao;

    // GET /posts /posts.json
    @RequestMapping(value = { "" }, method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String index(Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("posts", postDao.list());
        return "posts/index";
    }

    // GET /posts/1 GET /posts/1.json
    @RequestMapping(value = "/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String show(@PathVariable int id, Model model) {
        Post post = postDao.query(id);
        if (post != null) {
            model.addAttribute("post", post);
            return "posts/show";
        } else
            throw new RuntimeException("not found");

    }

    // GET /posts/new
    @RequestMapping(value = "/new", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String newForm(Model model) {
        model.addAttribute(new Post());
        return "posts/new";
    }

    // GET /posts/1/edit
    @RequestMapping(value = "/{id}/edit", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String edit(@PathVariable int id, Model model) {
        Post post = postDao.query(id);
        if (post != null) {
            model.addAttribute(post);
            return "posts/edit";
        } else
            throw new RuntimeException("not found");
    }

    // POST /posts /posts.json
    @RequestMapping(value = "", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String create(@Valid Post post, BindingResult result) {
        if (!result.hasErrors()) {
            postDao.add(post);
            return "redirect:/posts";
        } else {
            return "posts/new";
        }
    }

    // PUT /posts/1 /posts/1.json
    @RequestMapping(value = "/{id}", method = RequestMethod.PUT)
    public String update(@PathVariable int id, @Valid Post post, BindingResult result, RedirectAttributes redirectAttrs) {
        if (!result.hasErrors()) {
            post.setId(id);
            postDao.update(post);
            return "redirect:/posts/" + id;
        } else {
            return "posts/edit";
        }
    }

    // DELETE /posts/1 /posts/1.json
    @RequestMapping(value = "/{id}", method = RequestMethod.DELETE)
    public String destroy(@PathVariable int id, RedirectAttributes re) {
        Post p = new Post(id, "", "");
        postDao.delete(p);
        return "redirect:/posts";
    }
}
```

If I create a new simple model which need the curd operation,I will have to create a new controller,a new dao which is copy-paste manually.

So I wonder if I can find or create a tool which can generate controller and dao and etc accordingly like rails does?

Is there any tool I can use out-of-box? If not,I can create it,however by now,I just thought that if I have to create this kind of tool,I may just do something character replacement,that's to say,create a public template for controller and dao,then replace something accordingly,but I wonder how to handle the package/import/ problem,and which language is better (java or ruby)?

BTW,please do not recommend play!framework for me. I do not like it. Since I just want to use spring mvc. So the tool will only focus on controller and dao based on spring  3.

Any suggestion?

Comment: Not an answer but you may use GenericDAO for DAO layer. In my opinion  solutions like scaffolding is not suitable for production environment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Grails certainly provides this type of functionality out of the box, while I believe Spring Roo also does this for you. It's worth checking both out.

Comment: It seems that spring roo will use maven. And we work off-line.

Comment: Completely offline? You couldn't use an instance of Nexus to manage artifact downloads, meaning only that machine needs to be connected to the net?

Comment: Yes,Completely offline. Now I reply you in the specified computer which can access the network in another room.

Comment: You can always unmavenize & 'unrooize' your project once you have generated all necessary code.

Comment: The un-mavenizing approach is one way to go, but you lose the benefits that way. If you've one machine that can access this site, it can access the net. Set up a Nexus instance on that, then the other machines can simply connect to that machine. It stores the downloaded artifacts, so that each one is only downloaded from the net once.

Comment: @TrueDub +1! And he will take advantage of nexus repository in subsequent projects.

Comment: unfortunately,our work machine can never connect this machine which can access the net.  files from net can only be transferred to our work machine by usb.

Comment: That's a shame - you're really limiting your possibilities with that restriction.

Answer (score 1):

**Telosys** ( http://www.telosys.org/) is a lightweight code generator designed for this kind of job.

It can generate all the controllers, JSP, DAO, etc (and much more).

The principle is simple : the same template is applied for each entity you have defined.
All the templates are customizable (“.vm” files based on Velocity template engine) so you can have exactly what you want to generate (code structure, comments, etc)

Moreover a templates bundle for Spring MVC is already available, you can install it from GitHub : https://github.com/telosys-templates-v3/java7-web-mvc-spring-T300

For more information see this article https://modeling-languages.com/telosys-tools-the-concept-of-lightweight-model-for-code-generation/

Answer (score 0):

Check this also.

http://www.myeclipseide.com/documentation/quickstarts/ME4STutorialScaffoldingMVC/scaffoldingarticle.html

This is going to walk you through producing a ready-to-run Spring MVC application that implements the CRUD application pattern for a domain model.

*Disclaimer :This a 30 days trail version*